# Sliding down a row under another

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find out how I can slide the row currently occupied by the blah blah text under the row before it which will show more information. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong because right now when I click on it nothing hapapens?

I am not receiving any javascript errors.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:5px;">
                <a id="orderData" class="btn btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="8"><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
                    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
                    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>                        
    </tbody>
</table>

$(function() {
    $("td[colspan=8]").parent().hide();
    $("table").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1 ) {
            $target.slideUp();
            $target.closest("tr").prev().find("td:first").html("+");
        } else {
            $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
            if ($target.closest("tr").find("td:first").html() == "+")
                $target.closest("tr").find("td:first").html("-");
            else
                $target.closest("tr").find("td:first").html("+");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I would suggest redoing the table with divs as you will have more control and be able to manipulate the show/hide easier then using tables.

Comment: I am wondering if I"m not selecting the parent somewhere in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".info-toggler").on('click', function(event) {
        $(this).parents("tr").next().toggleClass("hide");
        $(this).children("i").toggleClass("fa-minus-circle").toggleClass("fa-plus-circle");
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th>Action</th>
</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td style="width:5px;">
    <a class="btn btn-xs info-toggler"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x"></i></a>
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="info-row hide">
  <td></td>
  <td colspan="10">
    <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td style="width:5px;">
    <a class="btn btn-xs info-toggler"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x"></i></a>
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="hide">
  <td></td>
  <td colspan="10">
    <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
  </td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table> 


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```